# How to load huge amount of Data ( like JSON or a text file) more than 30MB into HTML page (ex : within a div) using AngularJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, json

My requirement is to load a log file into a HTML File(ex : Div element) which is of more than 30MB it may be up to 100MB or more. 
    I am using AngularJS, AJAX, Jquery,CSS technologies. when I hit a link path to that data file will be hit and content will return into a object.
    I read this object and show that data in a HTML element. 
    When data increased to more than 30MB for example , page not responding. server side is JAVA technology with REST. At the end of the day i need to search a specific word or phrase in the loaded HTML using search box. My Problem is I am not able to load huge data into HTML. Example code below.

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl"> 



<div style="color:black;font-size:12px;">{{myWelcome}}</div>

</div>


<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $http, $timeout) {
  $http.get("http://localhost/assetdownload_0205/json/generated.json")
  .then(function(response) {
     // var myjson = JSON.parse(data);
      $timeout(function(){
       $scope.myWelcome = response.data;
      console.log("length",response.data);

      },2000);
       });

});
</script>
```

Comment: You may need to load the content in a lazy way and updating the DOM istead of directly printing.

Comment: You may implement some lazy loading process and only display parts of the data, which are currently desired to be used.

Comment: Can I have more information on lazy loading like an example ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try clarinet. It looks quite promising for handling streams: https://github.com/dscape/clarinet
Within each chunk opening or closing in your big file you can render something on the webpage streamlike.

This example shows usage without node:
https://github.com/dscape/clarinet/blob/master/samples/simple.html

Comment: Thanks Nils I will look into it and I hope it will help me to finish my job.

Comment: I am able to load 30MB file data into Div but after that browser is not responding for any operation on that page like ( search, copy).